# ISP DHCP takes precedence over WiFi DHCP

Tags: dhcp, wifi-configuration

I've TP-Link Archer c9 router. It connects to the Internet through Dynamic IP (DHCP from ISP). No MAC clone or other authorisation is necessary, it just work. DHCP is enabled on the WiFi router. But when I connect to it with my laptop (doesn't matter if with WiFi or wired), I get an IP from ISP DHCP, which is bad since I cannot access the router admin panel nor other devices in my LAN. Is there a setting where I can stop DHCP broadcast being submitted past the WiFi router (and reaching the ISP DHCP) or configuring a "preferred DHCP", if there is such a thing?

Comment: I'm surprised the DHCP broadcasts would cross a router at all, and even in both directions. Was some "DHCP relay" function accidentally activated? Strange VLAN and/or bridging setup? Network loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP has nothing to do with the DHCP allocations in your internal network.

I think that you have two routers, both acting as DHCP servers.
This setup cannot work.

You should login to the WiFi router and disable its function of DHCP server,
then reboot it and afterward reboot all devices on your internal network.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping DHCP services in the same broadcast zone.

You should be able to just disable the DHCP server you don't need.

If you absolutely need both, you need to separate them in different subnets, with proper isolation of the broadcast zones using a gateway router in between them.